# Выходит ошибка Route [post.destroy] not defined, что делать?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

хочу осуществить удаление поста по кнопке, но выходит ошибка, что такого роута не существует.
show.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <div class="post">
        <h3 class="post-title">{{$post->title}}</h3>
        <a href="{{route('post.store')}}">back</a>
        <a href="{{route('post.edit', $post->id)}}">edit</a>
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('post.destroy', $post->id)}}">
            @method('DELETE')
            @csrf
            
            <input type="submit" value="delete">
        </form>
    </div>
    
@endsection
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {return view('main');})->name('main.index');
Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index')->name('post.index');

Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@create')->name('post.create');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store')->name('post.store');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostController@show')->name('post.show');
Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit', 'PostController@edit')->name('post.edit');
Route::patch('/posts/{post}', 'PostController@update')->name('post.update');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}', 'PostController@destroy')->name('post.destroy');
```

PostController.php:

```
public function destroy(Post $post) {
        $post->delete();
        return redirect()->route('post.index');
}
```

Comment: Запустите команду "php artisan route:list" и добавьте скриншот результата в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Все дело было в том, что я когда то закешировал роуты и забыл об этом
Проект тестовый, много чего писал в консоль когда читал статьи по ларавелю

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).